# Jiffies to percentage in InfluxDB

Tags: influxdb, grafana, proxmox

I am collecting data from a Proxmox host into an InfluxDB datasource.
This datasource is used to power a Grafana dashboard.
Data is collected as it should, but I have a problem plotting
the CPU usage.

I have figured out that the data that is sent concerning the CPU
is sent as jiffies, so I figured that;

```
System / System + User + Idle = Percentage System CPU Usage
```

I then have to take a mean of all those values to get the mean System CPU usage for the last minute.
Here is where i run into a problem. 
The InfluxDB documentation states

> The use of mathematical operators inside of function calls is currently unsupported.

as can be found here [InfluxDB documentation](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v0.9/query_language/math_operators/)

My question is if there is a workaround for this so I can calculate the mean of a sum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to do this with InfluxDB, but its a two step process.

```
  SELECT System / (System + User + Idle) AS avg
  INTO "sys_cpu" FROM "my_measurement"
```

Then simply issue a query

```
SELECT mean(value) FROM "sys_cpu" GROUP BY time(<interval>)
```

Its kind of messy, but should work.

Comment: I switched to graphite since that proved to be a better solution for me. I think this will work for people using InfluxDB though, so I'll mark this as the answer.